# Machine Learning on financial big data

Tags: machine-learning, algorithmic-trading

*Disclaimer:* although I know some things about big data and am currently learning some other things about machine learning, the specific area that I wish to study is vague, or at least appears vague to me now. I'll do my best to describe it, but this question could still be categorised as too vague or not really a question. Hopefully, I'll be able to reword it more precisely once I get a reaction.

So,

I have some experience with Hadoop and the Hadoop stack (gained via using CDH), and I'm reading a book about Mahout, which is a collection of machine learning libraries. I also think I know enough statistics to be able to comprehend the math behind the machine learning algorithms, and I have some experience with R.
My ultimate goal is making a setup that would make trading predictions and deal with financial data in real time.

I wonder if there're any materials that I can further read to help me understand ways of managing that problem; books, video tutorials and exercises with example datasets are all welcome.

Comment: This question should probably be more appropriate in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ . Can someone migrate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take ML course on coursera. It is a good introductery into ML algorithms which will tell you what ML could do\some general approaches:
https://www.coursera.org/course/ml

Also to get a broader picture I suggest coursera's DataSciense course:
https://www.coursera.org/course/datasci

Finally a good book is Mahout in action - it is more about solving practical matters with mahout and has lots of examples and case-studies.
I beleive after that you will have a better understanding of what you want to do next.